# Flight with Ural Airlines delayed by one day - How to claim damages

Tags: air-travel, compensation

I planned a trip from the 17. august to the 21. august to St. Petersburg and book this fligth via a broker with Ural Airlines.

My return-flight was delayed by one day (25 hours). Which means I am eligibel to damages like Hotel-Costs plus 400€ under EU-Law.

I tried writing them an email to: info@uralairlines.ru but it was returned a few days later as undeliverd.

Is there an Email-address or another easy way for me to get in contact with them?

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE! Are you sure your return flight is covered by EU flight delay compensation rules? From the question I assumed the delayed flight occurred when you are travelling to Germany (according to your profile) using a Russian airline, which is not covered. If this is not the case can you please update the question?

Comment: any flight from and to the EU is covered

Comment: I don't think that is correct. Any flights from the EU are indeed covered, but any flights to the EU carry an extra condition that the carrier has to be based in a EU member state in order to be covered. (Source:  (EC) No 261/2004, Article 3, 1(b))

Comment: Articel 3,1b just says that the flight has to end in a member-state and that under some conditions u can't claim damages if you received assistance (which doesn't apply to me)

Comment: If the airline is outside the EU and the delayed flight originated outside the EU, then the issue is outside of EU jurisdiction i believe. That said, as it's a return leg of a flight that originated inside the EU, maybe it counts.

Comment: @zeocrash I guess [this EU interpretation (Point 2.1.2)](https://ec.europa.eu/transport/sites/transport/files/themes/passengers/news/doc/2016-06-10-better-enforcement-pax-rights/c%282016%293502_en.pdf) suggest otherwise on the treatment of return leg...

Comment: I thought that was probably the case.

Comment: @NDDT B.Liu's reading is right.  You are ignoring the last part of Art 3.1, which says that "*This Regulation shall apply ... to passengers departing from an airport located in a third country to an airport situated in the territory of a Member State to which the Treaty applies ... if the operating air carrier of the flight concerned is a Community carrier*".  The requirement about not having received assistance is in *addition* to the requirement about the country of registration of the carrier.  Your flight is not covered.

Comment: Yes, that might be right - I sent the email - they should at least cover my hotelcost and other expenses

Comment: @NDDT It is not at all obvious that the airline must compensate you for your hotel costs. If I understand the Russian rules for flight delay compensation correctly, the airline should have provided you some kind of accomodation for the night, but you are not entitled to reimbursment of your own expenses if you arranged a hotel booking yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't find anything about claiming damages on their website, neither any hints of contacts on their English web site.

You could try [Russian contact form](https://www.uralairlines.ru/good-info/online_help/). I would use `Другое` ("Other inquires") for the first drop-down and `Претензии` ("Claims") for the second.

Or you can phone them at +7-800-7700-262 or +7 (499) 920-22-52.

Comment: I send an email inquiring where to direct my claim with this contact form